# jQuery find similar attributes

Tags: jquery, search, attributes, href

My page has two 'tabbed' navigation sections. Both independent of one-another, but resulting in the same outcome. I figure the easiest way to go about coding them to work together, would be to find the `href' attribute that is the same from both sections, save it in a variable, and than continue from there.

My layout looks something like this.

```
<div id="tab-text">
    <a href="tab-1"></a>
    <a href="tab-2"></a>
    <a href="tab-3"></a>
</div>

<div id="tab-arrow">
    <a href="tab-1"></a>
    <a href="tab-2"></a>
    <a href="tab-3"></a>
</div>
```

And i have some jQuery like this.

```
jQuery('#tab-text a').click(function()
{
    jQuery('#tab-text a').removeClass('active');
    jQuery( this ).addClass('active');
}
```

So how can i include in the jQuery if `#tab-text a` is clicked, than find the value of the `href` attribute, and than search for that value from `#tab-arrow a` and `.addClass()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#tab-text a').click(function()
{
    jQuery('#tab-text a').removeClass('active');
    jQuery( this ).addClass('active');
    var searchHref = this.href;
    jQuery('#tab-arrow a[href="'+searchHref+'"]').doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Will `this.href` work? I believe it should be `$(this).attr('href')`.

Comment: @unclunorton -- no need for extra jQuery objects. `this.href` works just as well (maybe aven better)

Comment: hmm i wrote basically the same thing... `var active_tab = jQuery(this).attr('href');` So weird why its not working...

Comment: @cnotethegr8 -- are you following thru with the links? bc if you are you wont see the change. remember to add `return false;` to the end of this click function if u don't want the links to follow through

Comment: @Neal - ya thanks. i was calling the class's / id's via variables and i think i had missed a `.` or a `#` somewhere. Any ways its working now. Thanks

Comment: @cnote -- here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/V2Fnu/ (i used `split`)